# Gnome Shell Thunderbird Mail Notification

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-panel, thunderbird, notification

Does anyone know of a way to get persistent Gnome 3 panel notifications in Gnome 3 in  Oneiric? It's one of the few things holding me back from using Gnome 3 regularly.

I've actually found a way of moving the notifications from the (usually) hidden bottom bar to the top, but it does not move the Thunderbird icon. The icon also only tends to appear the first time mail is received. I'm very surprised this basic piece of functionality doesn't exist for Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switched from unity to Gnome Shell, and I came across this very problem.

there is this script made by @tanwald that you can get on [github](https://github.com/tanwald/gnome-shell-extension-thunderbird-integration). all that is left to do is to install th "install.sh"

(if you're not sure how to do it, follow these instrunctions [here](https://plus.google.com/112555004333838485342/posts/6teNeRdUAXK))

Comment: I'll have a look later .... thanks! I'm hopeful.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work. It does display a notification, but it is hidden at the bottom. I don't want something where I need to look to see if I have messages.

Comment: Tried this again, and it now seems to work. It's not perfect, as you frequently need to right-click and remove the thunderbird notifications at the bottom to make the top notification clear, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird is integrated with the messaging indicator, so you will get notified of new email as long as Thunderbird is running.

Comment: I want a persistent notification, not the libNotify popups.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. The envelope gets blue when there is new email, and if you click it, then you can see how many new emails there are, and what folders they're in.

Comment: I don't seem to have that for Gnome 3. Unity, yes, but not Gnome 3.

Comment: Unity is the default shell for Gnome 3 in Ubuntu. If you mean Gnome Shell, or some other shell, then you should say so. Gnome Shell has its own system, so you'll probably need to install a mail notification application or something.

Comment: Good point, I actually did mean to be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/) helps to change Thunderbird's behaviour?